# SSIS locks out of Account

Tags: sql-server, import, ssis

I designed an SSIS package that uploads CSV files to a SQL Server Database. The package works well on my computer, but when I try to run the .dtsx package on other computers it does not work and locks my account. Does anybody know how to write an SSIS package that can run on any computer? I'm a complete beginner with SSIS packages so any help would be great.

Comment: Did you use a configuration XML file?  This type of file can help you change where items are; for instance, you can change the connection string, where the folders and files are located.

Comment: Are you connecting to SQL Server using trusted/windows authentication or a SQL Server ID?  And when you say it locks out your account are you talking about an AD account or a SQL Server account?

Comment: I'm using a SQL Server ID and when it locks out the account, it's locking out my SQL Server Account @KennethFisher

Comment: How are you trying to run the package on other computers? What's the mechanism for making it go? Regardless of the mechanics, grab all of those log lines. I suspect you have a warning in there about "unable to decrypt XML node" or something to that affect

Comment: I am executing it through the Execute Package Utility

Answer (score 0):

In all probability you have your package set to a `ProtectionLevel` (package level property) set to `EncryptSensativeWithUserKey`.  This particular `ProtectionLevel` encrypts any password in the package (in this case your SQL Login password) using a combination of your login and machine names.  This means it can be opened only by you, and only from your machine.  Change it to `EncryptSensativeWithPassword` and set a `PackagePassword` (again a package level property).  You will have to use the package password when you go to execute it (from anywhere) but it should work regardless.

I'm not sure why it's locking out your id though.

Comment: At my company if you enter the wrong ID and password 3 times it locks your ID. Could this be related or would that not affect it at all.

Comment: It's possible.  I'm just not sure.  I honestly expected that if you tried to run it on another machine it just wouldn't work at all, not try to connect 3 times and fail.  If the fix I suggested works then that was probably it.  I'll test it out some time.

Comment: I changed this, but it still locks me out everytime I run it on another computer. Has anybody experienced this before?